# Show Images from outside of ASP.NET Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

So I'm having some trouble displaying images from outside of the project folder...

I seem to be only able to access images within the "~" directory and subdirectories...

**Say, if I want to access images from "E:/XYZ/11-01-01 New Year/" or something like that how may I do so?**

Note: I set privileges on all folders and sub folders as Readable to "Everyone" so IIS/Visual Studio should be able to but isn't showing the images in the Image Control

Comment: What code have you tried and what error/exception do you get?

Comment: The easiest is to set up a virtual directory in IIS, but that normally means the URL is publicly accessible without any authentication checks.  If you want to control access to the files based on login status/roles or if you want to do custom logging, then you would want to go the `IHTTPHandler` route.

Comment: @pauli: there is no error because the image controls don't throw errors... They just stay blank.

Answer (score 5):

You should use an [HttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx) to show the images.

Googling for "httphandler images" turns up numerous examples on how to do this.

Instead of trying to link directly to you images, you would link to the handler with the querystring determining which image to show. eg

```
http://mysite.com/MyHandler.ashx?image=myimage.jpg
```

Here's a very basic sample (minus error handling etc)

```
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
public class MyImageHandler : IHttpHandler 
{
    public void ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext ctx) 
    {

        string _Path;

        _Path = "E:\\XYZ\\11-01-01 New Year\\" + context.Request.QueryString["image"];

        ctx.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        ctx.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        ctx.Response.WriteFile(_Path);      
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get {return true; } }        
 }
```

Comment: why are you converting a string into a string ? *context.Request.QueryString["image"]* will return a string already.

Answer (score 2):

The client browser will never know where those images are unless you map a virtual directory to the images.  On your local test environment, you could work around this by referencing the image as "`file:///E:/XYZ/11-01-01 New Year/myimage.jpg`", but this is EXTREMELY bad practice and will never work in a production environment.  You should always use relative paths within the application's working directory, or a statically defined virtual directory located elsewhere.

Comment: yeah... I wont do the file:// thing although its good to know! thats interesting. I could expose a local folder on my website if directory browsing is enabled and then then it.d be like mywebsite.com/pictures

Comment: That sounds like a solution that should work, Fairzan.  Good luck.