# Physical Path for image saving. Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, security, file-upload, path

I have a web project and I saved my images in Physical folders in hdd Like `d:\SecretImages\Imagename`. But I can't open the files when I have to?

I thought if it can saves for examle `d:\SecretImages\Temp.jpg`, I can open when I have to but, I can't.

Help me please, thanks

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? Dead images on your site? Can you be more specific about what problems you're having? :)

Comment: I don't want anyone to get any images from my web site. So in insert pages i coded file paths to save d:\Images. But now in Edit pages I couldn't open my image files that is my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use file paths to show your images. The browser doesn't know where to find the images and the server wouldn't serve them up anyway due to security concerns.

You could/should use an [HttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx) to show the images.

I answered a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684673/show-images-from-outside-of-asp-net-application/4684769#4684769) on SO how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

its becus when iis get file, it get as ASP.NET user not local system user. just go to the folder and add **IIS_IURS** group to permission list. or just set folder accessible by everyone.
this type of problem mostly not occur when local debugging. but will happen in production or network storage.

Comment: I gave full permission to IIS_IURS but it didn't worked. My file path is "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Svn\\Final\\Project\\Services\\8\\wp.jpg" I thought it only works with virtual path?

Answer (score 0):

Try this article

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Images-in-GridView-Control-using-the-path-stored-in-SQL-Server-database.aspx