# how to load a picture to an <asp:Image> using a windows path

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wybuild

I have a little payments webApp, our customers can install it on their IIS and work with it. They can upload their own logotype.

We are using WyBuild to update this apps, but it replaces all files on the web folder with the new version, so the logotypes are deleted, that's why we placed the customer's files in program files, so the updater can't delete them.

the problem is that I can't load the images from the following path

```
C:\Program Files\MyApp\ImageFoder\logo.jpg
```

I don't know how to do it and I'm almost sure that is not possible to load

My web application is on

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\
```

I can't have the images on the webFolder because wyBuild deletes them when I'm trying to update them, I already tried the paths like this: (the don't work)

```
 ///file:c:/program files/ .... etc
```

so,  the question is

How can I load an image to an asp:image control using it's windows path ?

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843451/physical-path-for-image-saving-asp-net Hope it helps ;) Try to do a little search next time, so you don't create duplicates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to configure an IIS Virtual Folder to point to the alternate location where the images are stored.

I wouldn't put them in Program Files, though, a sibling folder in wwwroot would be better.

Remember NTFS permissions are easy to mess up and it's easier to manage them in a single place.

**Update - for locally installed, localhost-only sites** Alternatively (and this is only a good idea if you have minimal amounts of traffic. NOT for public websites), you can serve files from an arbitrary location using a VirtualPathProvider. It sounds like this 'web app' is installed like a desktop app for some reason? If you want to store user data externally, the user's App Data folder would be appropriate, but ONLY if the web app refuses external connections, and can only be accessed from the machine.

Since you're dealing with images, I'd [grab the imageresizing.net](http://imageresizing.net) library and use the VirtualFolder plugin to serve the files dynamically. It's 200KB more in your project, but you get free dynamic image resizing and/or processing if you need it, and you save a few *days* making a VirtualPathProvider subclass work (they're a nightmare).

Comment: I agree with Computer Linguist. Putting images to be referenced by a web application into Program Files is a REALLY bad idea from a security standpoint.

Comment: Is it possible to store images in different Virtual directory?

Comment: @Pankaj A virtual directory can be named anything - it's a virtual folder within the site, like /images or /assets/images. It can point to any physical location (even a remote server, although that is terribly problematic). But you have to make sure the NTFS permissions are correct so you don't have security problems.

Comment: @PankajGarg in my opinion there won't be a problem. You can have all your images stored on a different server completely. The only problem here is the IIS restrictions on how to treat local files...

Comment: @ComputerLinguist - You mean, I have to create another Virtual Directory and this will be outside the current Virtual Directory or inside ? My query is in context of IIS 7

Comment: Usually, you start with a Site or Application. A Virtual Directory can go inside either of those.

Comment: @ComputerLinguist Yes, I can do this sounds good, and also I was wondering if I could stored those images on the DB ... Thanks

Comment: Yes, you could store them in a DB, but you'd need the [SqlReader plugin](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/sqlreader), which isn't free (but it *is* cheap and redistributable). Where is the DB located? Locally?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to use isolated storage?
Added: I mean on the users machine, and upload them again if they are not found. This takes away your overhead completely.

Comment: hmm sorry I don't get it, what you mean with isolated storage ?

Comment: OK. I meant to turn the issue around. Instead of trying to protect and hide the icons from the updater, store them on the client side in isolated storage, so when the user accessess the site, a script checks for the local icon, if not found, then requsests it from the client. When new users from the same company access the site, a copy of the logo is placed in IS on their machine. Isolated Storage is safe and to be accessed from the web and your scripts can access it as standard (up to 1mb as standard). This is all fairly standard/same as cookies to some extent. Just a potential suggestion.