# Images not displaying in adrotator where its picture path like "C:\Uploader\Image.jpg"

Tags: asp.net, telerik

Images not displaying in adrotator where its picture path like "C:\Uploader\Image.jpg" or some shared folder in server.If i give the path inside my project,its working but outside the project ( like "C:\Uploader\Image.jpg") it not showing anything.

```
<telerik:RadRotator ID="radSlider" runat="server" FrameDuration="400" ScrollDuration="500"
ScrollDirection="Left" Height="250px" Width="550px">
<ItemTemplate>
    <img src='<%# Eval("FullName") %>' alt="Friday" width="550px" />
 </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadRotator>
```

Here i am attaching the path dynamically using databind.What is the problem.Plz help me?Telerik or asp control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client browser will never know where those images are unless you map a virtual directory to the images. Even you can not use `Server.MapPath()` etc to map the drive.

> You should use an [HttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx) to access  the file outside of your
>   application virtual directory.

Check following SO thread that much relevant to your problem:
[Show Images from outside of ASP.NET Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684673/show-images-from-outside-of-asp-net-application)

**Another approach that i have gotten after goggle about this as follow:**

You can try to access the file outside application's virtual directory. you need to pay attention to the folder/file enough permission.

you can to access the images in your website, you can  check the following link:

[Displaying images that are stored outside the Website Root Folder](http://archive.aspsnippets.com/post/2009/02/21/Displaying-images-that-are-stored-outside-the-Website-Root-Folder.aspx)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

if (Request.QueryString["FileName"] != null)

{

    try

    {

        // Read the file and convert it to Byte Array

        string filePath = "C:\\images\\";

        string filename = Request.QueryString["FileName"];

        string contenttype = "image/" +

        Path.GetExtension(Request.QueryString["FileName"].Replace(".","");

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath + filename,

        FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

        Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);

        br.Close();

        fs.Close();



        //Write the file to response Stream

        Response.Buffer = true;

        Response.Charset = "";

        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

        Response.ContentType = contenttype;

        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);

        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);

        Response.Flush();

        Response.End();

    }

    catch

    {

    }

}

}
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use IHttpHandler to serve your files in a different location (e.g. outside of application root or in privileged folders). AFAIK, Telerik Rad Controls has a RadBinaryImage or something for such usages.